# Estimate total distance using Riemann sum based on data table

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

We did not spend a lot of time in class on Riemann sum so I confused with this question.

Speedometer readings for a motorcycle at $12$-second intervals are given in the table below.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
t sec & 0 & 12 & 24 & 36 & 48 & 60 \\
\hline
v(t) ft/sec & 23 & 22 & 18 & 17 & 20 &23\\
\end{array}
$$

Estimate the total distance traveled during the time interval $[0,60]$ using a Riemann sum based on the table data.

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a Riemann sum is as following:

Let $f$ be a function, $\Pi=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ be a partition and $S=\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}$ a set of values such that $c_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$. The Riemann sum is
$$R(\Pi,S)=\sum_{i=1}^nf(c_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}).$$

You have a discrete function $f=v$ and you have a partition in first row of the table. Can you find the Riemann sum now?

Comment: Do I add all the $ft/sec$?
Since it is in a table already I do not have to create sub-intervals? 
I just want to understand everything

Comment: Not quite. The first row of the table are the $x_i$ values. The second row are the $f(c_i)$ values. You want the differences in the first row multiplied by the corresponding value in the second row and sum all of these. The difference is constant in this exercise.

Comment: ok so let me see if I understand.
$(23)(0-12-24-36-48-60)$+$(22)(0-12-24-36-48-60)$+$(18)(0-12-24-36-48-60)$ and the same for the rest?

Comment: Just $12\cdot23+12\cdot22+12\cdot18+\dots$

Comment: $12\cdot \left(23\right)+12\cdot \left(22\right)+12\cdot \left(18\right)+12\cdot \left(17\right)+12\cdot \left(20\right)+12\cdot \left(23\right)$?

Comment: Looks correct to me :)

Comment: it is saying that $1476$ is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19453/discussion-between-slo-and-bs319).